# Iteration over for loop in r

Tags: r

I am programming R and am confronted with the following syntax errorÖ

Here is the code:

> for (i in (1:7)) {for (index in seq(i,56,8)) {values[[length(values)+1]] <- c(ADDLINEORDER[index]) }  time_series_values[[length(time_series_value)+1]] <- values}

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "for (i in (1:7)) {for (index in seq(i,56,8)) {values[[length(values)+1]] <- c(ADDLINEORDER[index]) }  time_series_values"
```

what I want is: lets say that there is a vector `(1,5,6,7,3,9)` as input

As I result I want to have it like `((1,6,3),(5,7,9))`

1 5 are the starting points, I want it to be iterated by 2 so (1, 6, 9) are together in one list.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you explain in plain english the output that you want, or at least provide some sample data and a sample of what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Spacedman has found the problem.  Formatting properly also fixes it:

```
for ( i in (1:7) ) {
  for ( index in seq(i, 56, 8) ) {
    values[[ length(values) + 1 ]] <- c( ADDLINEORDER[index] ) 
  }
  time_series_values[[ length(time_series_value) + 1 ]] <- values
}
```

Comment: Thanks working now I had to initialize the empty lists, always thought that R creates it dynamically when not existing

Comment: R will stretch lists and vectors, but not create them for you. Always a good idea to explicitly create them (thing=list()) so you dont get odd bugs because you are stomping on something pre-existing.

Answer (score 4):

Missing semicolon. You pasted this into one line from something that was more than one line?

```
for (i in (1:7)) {for (index in seq(i,56,8)) {values[[length(values)+1]] <- c(ADDLINEORDER[index]) }; time_series_values[[length(time_series_value)+1]] <- values}
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the "paste as one line" problem, though better to space out over multiple lines than encourage use of `;`.

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look. Adding ; did not solve the issue

Comment: Adding `;`, or putting in a new line at that point, solved it for me -- or at least got me to the error `Error: object 'ADDLINEORDER' not found`, not surprising since you haven't specified it above. Can you give us a reproducible example please ... ?

Comment: Bob: You might gain by learning to execute code line-by-line.   Put all your loop code into a new document, and execute it a line at a time.  This way you'll know which line has the (most likely) messed-up sequence of "{" , "[" and so on.

Since gsk3 seems to indicate his code ran, you must have mis-copied something.